# How to handle a Cross-thread operation not valid when accessing Controls accessed from a different thread?

Tags: .net, vb.net, multithreading, winforms

I want to periodically check a local area network db connection.
IN simple words, I set a timer (it ticks every 5 sec) that runs the database check.
This procedure is freezing the Form, so I tried to run this code in a Thread and also to make use of the async/await pattern to solve this.
With my current code, when I try to access a Control, I have an exception:

> Cross-thread operation not valid: Control `StatusStrip1` accessed from
> a thread other than the thread it was created on.

I found problems like this solved using `Control.Invoke()`, but I cannot figured out how to implement it.
I'm trying to access a ProgressBar and a StatusLabel on ToolStrip.

How can I solve the Form freezing problem and avoid exceptions?

I'm using VB.net 2019

[image: screenshot]

Here is my code:

```
Private Sub MyBGThread()
    If CheckConDB(ConStringDB1) Then
        TSSPBar.BackColor = Color.Green
        TSSPBar.ForeColor = Color.Green
    Else
        TSSPBar.BackColor = Color.Red
        TSSPBar.ForeColor = Color.Red
    End If
End Sub
Private Async Sub TmrDB_Tick(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles TmrDB.Tick
    ' Dim thread As New Thread(AddressOf MyBGThread)
    ' thread.Start()
    Await Task.Run(Sub() MyBGThread())
End Sub
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could just do:

```
Private Async Sub TmrDB_Tick(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles TmrDB.Tick
    Dim result As Boolean = Await Task.Run(Function() CheckConDB(ConStringDB1))
    TSSPBar.BackColor = If(result, Color.Green, Color.Red)
    TSSPBar.ForeColor = If(result, Color.Green, Color.Red)
End Sub
```

Comment: Well done Idle_Mind, very close to my code and it works... Thank you

Answer (score 1):

If your synchronous `CheckConDB()` method can be converted to an async one, do that so you can more easily await a result from it. If it cannot be async, a couple of options:

(My suggestion is not to await in a `Timer.Tick` event when you don't know how much the awaited method will take to complete. The Timer ticks anyway).

**Using [`BeginInvoke()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.control.begininvoke)**:
This method posts to the UI Thread and doesn't block. You don't need to check `InvokeRequired`, this method can be called safely from the same Thread or a worker Thread.

Add a Field that stores a [CancellationTokenSource](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.threading.cancellationtokensource):

```
Private checkDbCts As CancellationTokenSource = Nothing
```

In `Form.Load` (or when you decide to, but after the Controls you need to interact with have created their handles) run this Task, specifying the Interval between calls to `CheckConDB()`; pass a [CancellationToken](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.threading.cancellationtoken) generated by your CancellationTokenSource:

```
checkDbCts = New CancellationTokenSource()
Task.Run(Function() MyBGThread(1000, bgThreadCts.Token))
```

The Task will await `[Interval]` milliseconds before each call to `CheckConDB()`. If the Task is canceled (when [`CancellationTokenSource.Cancel()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.threading.cancellationtokensource.cancel) is called), it will terminate and exit.

When `CheckConDB()` returns a result, `BeginInvoke()` calls the `ProgressUpdate` method, passing a Color based on the value of the result.

```
Private Async Function MyBGThread(interval As Integer, token As CancellationToken) As Task
    token.ThrowIfCancellationRequested()
    Try
        While True
            Await Task.Delay(interval, token)
            Dim result As Boolean = CheckConDB(ConStringDB1)
            Dim ctrlColor As Color = If(result, Color.Green, Color.Red)
            BeginInvoke(New Action(Sub() ProgressUpdate(ctrlColor)))
        End While
    Catch tce As TaskCanceledException
        Return
    End Try
End Function
```

**Using an [IProgress(Of T)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.iprogress-1) delegate** (this is the preferred method):

Add a Field that stores the delegate, keep the `CancellationTokeSource` Field declare before:

```
Private checkDbProgress As IProgress(Of Color) = Nothing
```

In `Form.Load()`, create a new `Progress(Of T)` delegate and start the Task, passing the delegate, set to the `ProgressUpdate()` method, an Interval and a CancellationToken:

```
checkDbProgress = New Progress(Of Color)(Sub(c) ProgressUpdate(c))
checkDbCts = New CancellationTokenSource()
Task.Run(Function() MyBGThread(checkDbProgress, 1000, checkDbCts.Token))
```

The `MyBGThread()` is modified to accept a `Progress(Of T)` object.
Its [Report()](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.iprogress-1.report) method will call the `ProgressUpdate()` method in the UI Thread, since `IProgress(Of T)` captures the [SynchronizationContext](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.threading.synchronizationcontext) of the Thread where it's initialized and dispatches messages asynchronously to that Thread using the method delegate specified.

```
Private Async Function MyBGThread(progress As IProgress(Of Color), interval As Integer, token As CancellationToken) As Task
    Try
        While True
            Await Task.Delay(interval, token)
            Dim result As Boolean = CheckConDB(ConStringDB1)
            Dim ctrlColor As Color = If(result, Color.Green, Color.Red)
            progress.Report(ctrlColor)
        End While
    Catch tce As TaskCanceledException
        Return
    End Try
End Function
```

The `ProgressUpdate()` method is called in both cases and in both cases it executes in the UI Thread: you can interact with UI elements here.

```
Private Sub ProgressUpdate(ctrlColor As Color)
    TSSPBar.BackColor = ctrlColor
    TSSPBar.ForeColor = ctrlColor
End Sub
```

Comment: Thank you Jimi, your explanation is great but i still dont really understand about it now, but i'll try later, because i guess i'll need to implement to my realtime-preview. I'm sure it works

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
Private Sub MyBGThread()
    If CheckConDB(ConStringDB1) Then
        SetTSSPBarColor(Color.Green, Color.Red)
    Else
        SetTSSPBarColor(Color.Red, Color.Green)
    End If
End Sub

Private Sub SetTSSPBarColor(ForeC As Color, BackC As Color)
    If Me.InvokeRequired Then
        Me.Invoke(Sub()
                      SetTSSPBarColor(ForeC, BackC)
                  End Sub)
    Else
        TSSPBar.ForeColor = ForeC
        TSSPBar.BackColor = BackC
    End If
End Sub
```